# Get values for today, last_week and last_year for every date

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that lists the daily logins per channel to a website since 2020. ROW_NUM column gives the row number partitioned by REPORTING_YEAR and REPORTING_WEEK.

[image]

I need to create a view for a report, that has logins for same day last week, and same day last year as well for every given date.

I have tried a simple subquery below which should, in theory, get the results but it throws an unsupported subquery error in Snowflake.

```
SELECT D1.REPORTING_YEAR,
    D1.ACTIVITY_DATE,
    D1.REPORTING_WEEK,
    D1.CHANNEL,
    D1.LOGINS,
    D1.ROW_NUM,
    (SELECT 
        D2.LOGINS 
        FROM DAILY_LOGINS D2
        WHERE D2.REPORTING_WEEK = D1.REPORTING_WEEK-1
        AND D2.CHANNEL = D1.CHANNEL
        AND D2.ROW_NUM = D1.ROW_NUM
        ) AS LAST_WEEK_LOGINS
    FROM DAILY_LOGINS D1;
```

I can use a LAG function to calculate last_week's data but I don't see how I can get the last year's.
Any ideas on how I can get this data?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is to use left joins to the same table. This takes time to execute, but produces the desired output.

```
    SELECT D1.REPORTING_YEAR,
       D1.ACTIVITY_DATE,
       D1.REPORTING_WEEK,
       D1.CHANNEL,
       D1.LOGINS,
       D1.ROW_NUM,
       D2.LOGINS AS LAST_WEEK_LOGINS,
       D3.LOGINS AS LAST_YEAR_LOGINS
FROM DAILY_LOGINS D1
LEFT JOIN DAILY_LOGINS D2
    ON D2.ACTIVITY_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -7, D1.ACTIVITY_DATE)
    AND D2.CHANNEL= D1.CHANNEL
LEFT JOIN DAILY_LOGINS D3
    ON D3.REPORTING_YEAR = D1.REPORTING_YEAR-1
    AND D3.REPORTING_WEEK = D1.REPORTING_WEEK
    AND D3.ROW_NUM = D1.ROW_NUM
ORDER BY ACTIVITY_DATE,CHANNEL
```

If someone can provide a better optimized answer, it's appreciated.